CSS fade out div and fade in new div
I have a grid of buttons, and when one of the buttons is clicked I want the grid to fade out, and a new div to fade in replacing the space of the buttons, so I have animations for opacity 1->0 and vice versa, with adding/removing display:none so the content is replaced.
I have this working (possibly not the cleanest solution as still new to animations) but in the new div I have a back button which will do the opposite (fade out new div, fade in original grid). I have nearly got this working, the new div fades out correctly, but the original grid snaps back in initially and then fades in, and I am not sure how to get this fixed.
(Not sure if this is relevant but I am doing this in Angular but I have converted to vanilla JS) Here is my code, and a codepen


function showAccordion(){
    document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('fadeOut');
  setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('hide-element');
      document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.add('fadeIn');
      document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.add('show-element');
    }, 1000);
  }

function resetAccordion(){
    document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.remove('fadeIn');
    document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.add('fadeOut');
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.remove('show-element');

    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() =>{
      document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.remove('fadeOut');
      document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.remove('hide-element');
      document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('fadeIn');

    },2000)
  }
.faq-support-boxes-grid {
  background-color: #fff;
      display: grid;
      gap: 1rem;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);

      opacity: 1;

      .feature-box{
        background-color:#a6a6a6;
        text-align:center;
        img{
          display: inline;
          width:40%;
        }
      }
    }

    .fadeOut {
      animation: fadeOutTop 1s ease-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .fadeIn {
      animation: fadeInTop 1s ease-out 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    .accordion-container{
      transform: translateY(-30rem);
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
      transition: all 1s;
    }

    .accordion-container > div{
      display: none;
    }

    .accordion-back{
      transform: translateY(-10%);
      display: block;
      color:#325390 !important;
    }

    .show-element{
      display: block !important;
    }
    .hide-element{
      display: none !important;
    }

@keyframes fadeOutTop{
  0%{
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0rem);
  }
  100%{
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(-30rem);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInTop{
  100%{
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0rem);
  }
  0%{
      opacity: 0 ;
      transform: translateY(-30rem);
  }
}
<div id="faq-support-boxes-grid" class="faq-support-boxes-grid">
   <div id="feature-box-about" onclick="showAccordion()" class="feature-box" tabindex="1">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-security" onclick="showAccordion()" class="feature-box" tabindex="2">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading  2</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-using" class="feature-box" tabindex="3">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-account" class="feature-box" tabindex="4">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 4</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-billing" class="feature-box" tabindex="5">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 5</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-support" class="feature-box" tabindex="6">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 6</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="accordion-container" class="accordion-container">
   <button class="accordion-back btn btn-secondary" onclick="resetAccordion()">
   Back
   </button>
</div>




It looks like the snaps back happens because .fadeIn class sets animation delay to 1 second.

I see some strange, in code, like you do
document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.add('fadeIn'); but
document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('fadeIn');

@Yorgi thats because I want the fade in to always start after the fade out, is that the problem?

@zb' can you eleborate?

@WhatsThePoint I not sure what you tried to do, I would to make such better with just  two classes one on "buttons" and other on "answers" and using just transition without keyframes, as they overkill here, also may be you think wrong about "timeouts" they are counting together, not sequential.  Also with animation is better to use "visibility: hidden" instead of "display: none" , also I think tehre is too much "ids"

@zb' I admit its a bit messy from trying various things. The display:none is so the content takes the same position

the for sure pronlem here that you set class on one element and remove it from another, try to clean up problem  by making simple snippet, with clear code, I tried to fix your but it messy

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can try like below changes. Add new class Op0 which will set the Opacity (transperancy) of the element to 0. So, when you will fadeIn grid will not snaps back in initially, it will get display: block but due to transparency will be 0 it won't be visible. And later with the animation from fadeIn it will get proper visiblility.

add following css inside .faq-support-boxes-grid { ... before .fadeOut css.

   /* Add following css */
   .Op0 {
     opacity: 0;
   }


Update showAccordion() function. Replace first line document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('fadeOut'); with following lines.

    // remove class fadeIn
    document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.remove('fadeIn');
    // add Op0 class along with fadeOut
    document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('fadeOut', 'Op0');


Update resetAccordion() function. Move below line from second setTimeout to first setTimeout.

   document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('fadeIn');

Try complete code below.


function showAccordion(){
    // remove class fadeIn
    document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.remove('fadeIn');
    // add Op0 class along with fadeOut
    document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('fadeOut', 'Op0');
  setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('hide-element');
      document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.add('fadeIn');
      document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.add('show-element');
    }, 1000);
  }

function resetAccordion(){
    document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.remove('fadeIn');
    document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.add('fadeOut');
    setTimeout(() => {
      // move adding fadeIn class here from next setTimeout function
      document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.add('fadeIn');

    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() =>{
      document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.remove('fadeOut');
      document.getElementById('faq-support-boxes-grid')?.classList.remove('hide-element');
      document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.remove('show-element');

    },2000)
  }
.faq-support-boxes-grid {
  background-color: #fff;
      display: grid;
      gap: 1rem;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);

      opacity: 1;

      .feature-box{
        background-color:#a6a6a6;
        text-align:center;
        img{
          display: inline;
          width:40%;
        }
      }
    }
    
    /* Add following css */
    .Op0 {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .fadeOut {
      animation: fadeOutTop 1s ease-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .fadeIn {
      animation: fadeInTop 1s ease-out 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    .accordion-container{
      transform: translateY(-30rem);
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
      transition: all 1s;
    }

    .accordion-container > div{
      display: none;
    }

    .accordion-back{
      transform: translateY(-10%);
      display: block;
      color:#325390 !important;
    }

    .show-element{
      display: block !important;
    }
    .hide-element{
      display: none !important;
    }

@keyframes fadeOutTop{
  0%{
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0rem);
  }
  100%{
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(-30rem);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInTop{
  100%{
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0rem);
  }
  0%{
      opacity: 0 ;
      transform: translateY(-30rem);
  }
}
<div id="faq-support-boxes-grid" class="faq-support-boxes-grid">
   <div id="feature-box-about" onclick="showAccordion()" class="feature-box" tabindex="1">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 1</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-security" onclick="showAccordion()" class="feature-box" tabindex="2">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading  2</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-using" class="feature-box" tabindex="3">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-account" class="feature-box" tabindex="4">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 4</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-billing" class="feature-box" tabindex="5">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 5</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div id="feature-box-support" class="feature-box" tabindex="6">
      <img src="https://www.adaptivewfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-placeholder-image.png" >
      <h3>Heading 6</h3>
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="accordion-container" class="accordion-container">
   <button class="accordion-back btn btn-secondary" onclick="resetAccordion()">
   Back
   </button>
</div>




thank you for this, you're amazing, slight tweak I had to do, was that because this wasn't the bottom of the page, it was jumping up content below because both were display:none at the same time, so I document.getElementById('accordion-container')?.classList.remove('show-element'); to the second setTimeout()
